# Batch Apex Error - Row with duplicate Id

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

I have the below scheduled batch class to run every month. The purpose is count Asset records per Account and then create a custom object (Track__c) record for each associated account showing that count. It's meant to have records for each month for tracking. When I run the batch, I get an error message:

***Failed to process batch for class 'RecordsBatch' for job id '7071h00001B1EUX' ||
caused by: System.ListException: Row with duplicate Id at index: 32 ||
Class.RecordsBatch.execute: line 16, column 1***

I'm unsure what the duplicate record is, the Asset or Account. Is there something I am missing that is causing this error?

```
public class RecordsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Asset)]);
    }

Date PriorMonth = System.today().toStartOfMonth().addMonths(-1);
Date CurrentMonth  = System.today().toStartOfMonth();
Integer ActiveAmt;

    public void execute(Database.batchableContext context, List<Account> scope) {

        List<Tracker__c> RecList = new List<Tracker__c>();

        Map<Id, AggregateResult> activeRec = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
            SELECT AccountId Id1, COUNT(Id) amt1, EndDate
            FROM Asset 
            WHERE AccountId = :scope AND AccountId != Null AND EndDate >=:CurrentMonth AND EndDate <> NULL GROUP BY AccountId, EndDate]);

        for(Account record: scope) {
            AggregateResult activeCount = activeRec.get(record.Id);
                if(activeCount != null) {
                    ActiveAmt = (Integer)activeCount.get('amt1');
                } else {
                    ActiveAmt = null;
                }
            Tracker__c ct = new Tracker__c(Account_Name__c = record.Id, Date__c = PriorMonth, Active__c = ActiveAmt);
                RecList.add(ct);
            }
        insert RecList;
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc)
    {
        BatchSchedule__c b = BatchSchedule__c.getOrgDefaults();
            b.Scheduled_Id__c = system.scheduleBatch(new RecordsBatch(),'Batch 2'+System.currentTimeMillis(),2);
        upsert b;
    }
}
```

Comment: the error message refers to a class name not shown. What is line 16?

Comment: Sorry, I changed the name of the class after the error to create a copy to work from. The error does apply to the class shown and line 16 is the first map AggregateResult.

Comment: i think it is because the same accountId appears across multiple endDates

Comment: I thought it might be the accounts. Do you know of a way to aggregate the child records without running into duplicate parents?

Comment: Idea: don't transform the aggregate query directly into the Map, instead, run through the results in a for loop and build your own tallies